# Launch wifi setting activity in full screen

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to create a project which needs to call android wifi setting screen . my project needs to run on full screen mode so this is my AndroidManifest.xml file .

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fullscreenwifi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

in Main activity i placed a button and this is my button onClick method

```
public void onClick(View v)
   startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
}
```

when i click on this button it launches wifi setting screen but this screen **not launching with full screen mode** . I am totally struck with this problem . Is there anyway to call this wifi setting screen along with full screen mode ? . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't force the settings app to launch in full screen mode through your code.

The Settings app is an independent app, which has been designed to run without fullscreen. By using an Intent, you launch the Settings app. The user is no longer in your app, and hence you can't control the full screen state of the displayed activity.

Comment: Oh man !! . So should i create my own custom wifi setting screen and display along with my project ?

Comment: @Nagarajan I wouldn't recommend it. There's no sense in breaking a user's expected workflow and not showing a wifi settings screen that they're used to because of a status bar being shown. You'd also need to write your own wifi toggling code into your settings screen, as you won't be able to use the system one anymore. But yes, it is entirely possible to do this.

Comment: @Nagarajan Please accept the answer if it answered your query!

Comment: @Nagarajan have you created your own custom wifi setting screen? i need to have it because my app is must limit user to go outside it ( commercial issue )

Comment: @JackTurky Yes i created custom wifi setting screen but i added limited information only like displaying list of wifi hotspots ( Client requirement )